# Android MediaPlayer plays sound with lower volume the first time

Tags: android

This is the code I'm using to create a notification sound. However, the media player plays the sound with a lower volume when the function is called for the first time. If this function is immediately called again, it then plays with the desired volume which is the stream volume.

```
Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getActualDefaultRingtoneUri(context, 
RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(context, notification);
                mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
                mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new 
MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mMediaPlayer.setVolume(1, 1);
                        if(!mMediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                           mMediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                });

                mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new 
MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mMediaPlayer.release();
                    }
                });

                mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
```

How to play the sound with the right volume at all times?

Comment: Does it make any difference if you try using different stream type(s) i.e AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC ?

Comment: I want to specifically use STREAM_RING

Comment: Ok, asking that rather to check does somewhat common ascending ring tone volume possibly affect the programmatic use you face also.

Comment: Changing it to STREAM_ALARM also produces the same result

Comment: But you're right, this might be a problem of the ascending ringtone volume. This happens on the Motorola phone I'm testing but not on a Xiaomi phone.